# Редактирование переменной до конкретного символа

Tags: python

Скрипт определяет местоположение юзера в формате "**Аsia/Yekaterinburg**", но передавать другому скрипту он должен лишь город, то есть формат "**Yekaterinburg**". Нужно убрать все символы до "/" включительно, это возможно?

Comment: `print( "Аsia/Yekaterinburg".split('/')[-1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return "Asia/Yekaterinburg".split('/')[1];
```

P.S. если скрипт передает другому